# Angular 2 dependency injection for decorators

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

Is there any way to inject a service dependency into a `@Component` decoration, something like this?

```
@Component({
    selector: injectedService.getPrefix() + 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent { }
```

Or, if not, might it be possible to subsclass `@Component` and inject a dependency into the subclass to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update >= RC.5**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap(moduleRef) {
    appInjector(moduleRef.injector);
  }
}
```

`appInjector` implementation see below

**original <= RC.5**

This is not directly supported by Angular2. You can store the injector outside of your Angular app and then reference it from there like demonstrated as a workaround for the `@CanActivate()` decorator in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572.
([**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ?p=preview))

In `main.ts` the injector is assigned to `appInjector`

```
bootstrap(App, [
  Auth,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]).then((appRef: ComponentRef) => {
  // store a reference to the application injector
  appInjector(appRef.injector);
});
```

`app-injector.ts`

```
let appInjectorRef: Injector;
export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector):Injector => {
    if (injector) {
      appInjectorRef = injector;
    }

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

then you can get a reference to the injector like

```
appInjector()...
```

This won't work if the component is created before `bootstrap()` is completed.

Comment: any idea how to do this in ng2 release?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, your update does not work for me in Angular 2.2.2. Suggestion by using a constructor : `export class AppModule {constructor(injector: Injector) {appInjector(injector);}}`