# Inject angular\core service manually, not through constructor

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to build a component factory for a popover type controller in my Angular2 app.

I have it working now where I pass in all dependencies and my component to the controller, and create via componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory which works out well enough.

I would like for the caller to not have to pass in references to the dependencies but cannot figure out how to manage that. I have tried playing with ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate but can't quite seem to manage.

How do I set this up so that I can access ComponentFactoryResolver and ViewContainerRef without having to import and pass out via all consumers of this service? See current setup below

Caller/Presenter

```
myPopover = new PopoverController(this.componentFactoryResolver, this.viewContainerRef, MyComponent);
```

PopoverController

```
constructor (private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private myComponent: Component){
    let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(<Type<Component>>myComponent);
    let res = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
}
```

The above works great and builds the myComponent perfectly well, I'd just like to not have to keep passing around refs to ComponentFactoryResolver and viewContainer from my caller, who in theory should not care about those services.

I tried something like the below but haven't managed to make it work

```
var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReflectiveInjector` creates a new injector instance and isn't applicable. Injector instance should be passed by reference from another injectable. If there's no injector instance available, root injector can be obtained with [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821535/angular-2-dependency-injection-for-decorators) (and probably indicates the problem with design).

`ViewContainerRef` isn't normal `@angular/core` service, it doesn't refer to a singleton instance but to an instance that is specific to particular component. It can't be retrieved with injector.

Of course, `viewContainerRef` needs to be passed by reference.

[It has `injector` property](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html), this means that no other dependencies need to be passed alongside with `viewContainerRef`, they can be retrieved in-place:

```
const { injector } = viewContainerRef;
const componentFactoryResolver = injector.get(ComponentFactoryResolver);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the accepted answer above, I found a way to use [Factory Providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers) to accomplish this more generically than relying on the relationship between `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver` classes, although my code ironically enough needed them too :)

**my.service.provider.ts**

```
import {MyService} from './my.service';
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  RendererFactory2,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

const myServiceFactory = (rendererFactory, viewContainer, componentFactoryResolver) => {
  return new MyService(rendererFactory, viewContainer, componentFactoryResolver);
};

export const MyServiceProvider = {
  provide: MyService,
  useFactory: myServiceFactory,
  deps: [RendererFactory2, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver]
};
```

**Excerpt from component requiring service**

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyServiceProvider],
  ...
})
```